# QGIS Filter x and y coordinates

Tags: qgis

I have a layer with a lot of polygons. Now I want to filter all polygons that are very narrow. 
For example, the polygons show living space. But I'm only interested in large living spaces. Function $area does not help here, as there are also very long and narrow surfaces. 
Does anyone know a function in QGIS that comes to this output via filtering x and y?

Comment: You could use the `point of inaccessibility` and its distance to the polygons border?

Comment: Do you mean checking the difference of max_x minus min_x (or y) is very small? So you can do QGIS expression to select them according to a defined threshold.

Comment: I tried that: new field -> xmax ($geometry) - xmin ($geometry). And the same for y. But I'm still missing something. That does not help me yet.

Comment: @hugo - If you want to ignore long, narrow polygons which, for example, have an average width of 10m, you could use a query like `area(buffer($geometry, -5)) > 0`. This query creates a negative buffer (i.e. inwards) and if the area of the buffer is greater than 0 then that polygon has a greater width.

Comment: This works very well! Thanks! Can you explain to me what significance the -5 has here?

Comment: @hugo - The negative value is creating a buffer where it contracts on all sides. So `-5` means the buffer will have each side which is 5m inwards from the original distance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ignore long, narrow polygons which, for example, have an average width of 10m, you could use a query like:

```
area( buffer($geometry, -5 )) > 0
```

This query creates a negative buffer (i.e. inwards) and if the area of the buffer is greater than 0 then that polygon has a greater width. You can change the value to set a threshold more suited for your needs.